# Openpose CMakeLists

Tags: macos, terminal, cmake, openpose

Having trouble building Openpose. Got to the "OpenPose Building" heading on MacOS, however the CMakeLists.txt for caffe (in 3rdparty) doesn't exist.

Where do I find this or is there a work around?

Below is my terminal output...

```
CMake Error: The source directory "/Users/Somaya/Desktop/Openpose/3rdparty/caffe" does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt.
Specify --help for usage, or press the help button on the CMake GUI.
make[2]: *** [caffe/src/openpose_caffe-stamp/openpose_caffe-configure] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/openpose_caffe.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I ran the command...

```
make -j`nproc`
```

in the build folder.

Comment: What was your command and what folder did you run it on?

Comment: @Chris make -j`nproc` in the build folder - ill update the question

Comment: It has been quite a while since I've looked at this (albeit on Windows).. I'm looking at some of the documentation and they seem to note something specific with caffe. Have you tried/gave a look at [this](https://github.com/CMU-Perceptual-Computing-Lab/openpose/blob/master/doc/installation.md#mac-osx-version)?

Comment: @Chris it worked! Thank you so much